# How to parse JSON passing in PHP web service

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to pass a JSON: `{"name":"jason","age":"20}` in PHP though **POST**

In RoR, I can get the two values by using `params["name"]` & `params["age"]`

But I don't know how to get them in PHP.

I understand that I can 'translate' the JSON string into associative array by using `json_decode` but I don't know how to get the JSON string.

In my **PHP code**, I has tried something like this:

```
<?php
    $json_string = $_POST['params'];

    $json_object= json_decode($json_string);
    print_r($json_object);

    echo $json_object->name;
    echo " ";
    echo $json_object->age;
?>
```

Then I has tested the PHP with terminal and I got the **correct** result

```
curl -d 'params={"name":"jason", "age":"20"}' xxxx/test_json_decode.php
```

It works but it seems strange to me, because I didn't set the `'Content-Type: application/json'`

Is it the correct way to parse JSON in PHP?

Comment: the content-type is only useful in certain cases, such as jquery doing a standard .post where you haven't explicitly told it to expect a json response. a json string is just text, and the content-type is just a clue to the receiver. but you could still send a json string with `image/jpeg` and still decode it and get a native structure again.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment, so the way I used to pass the JSON into PHP is correct ?

Comment: yes, as long as what you pass into json_decode is the json string, then it's valid, regardless of the mime-type it was sent across with.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks you so much :) You can reply to this question then I can      'tick' on your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content-type is only useful in certain cases, such as jquery doing a standard .post where you haven't explicitly told it to expect a json response. A json string is just text, and the content-type is just a clue to the receiver. but you could still send a json string with image/jpeg and still decode it and get a native structure again.

As long as what you pass into json_decode() is a valid JSON string, regardless of the mime-type it was sent with, it'll be decoded into a native structure.